# get me the value of multi dimensional php array with subarrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
    static $countryList = array(
       ["AF" => "Afghanistan"],
       ["AL" => "Albania"],
       ["DZ" => "Algeria"],
       //many more countries
      );
```

I want to do something like `$countryList['DZ']` to get "Algeria"

why those damned sub arrays?

well, some countries must come twice

basically this...

```
    static $countryList = array(
       ["US" => "USA"],
       ["AL" => "Albania"],
       ["DZ" => "Algeria"],
       //...
       ["UB" => "Uganda"],
       ["US" => "USA"]
      );
```

it's used for a select list

Comment: @hanshenrik He explained why he did it, because he needs to allow duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another array that's an associative array:

```
$countryMap = [];
foreach ($countryList as $country) {
    foreach ($country as $short => $long) {
        $countryMap[$short] = $long;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `$countryMap["DZ"]`

Comment: I was hoping there might be a better solution that iterating through the array

Comment: Nope, there's nothing built in that searches sub-arrays.